# Operate 2 wlan systems on windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have buildt my own IOT Hub like application. There are a multitude of ESP microcontrolers, which are sending sensor data to a server. This server is taking the data and storing it to a database.

So far this works well. However the Ip-Address of the wifi device should not change, as the Ip-Addresses where the ESPs send their data is programmed to the ESP decices.

Now I want to add internet to the server.

In some proximity to the server I have a wifi rooter, in between I have mounted an wifi range extender, to extend the network to my server.

The operating system I use is windows 10.
The two wifi range extender I use are: Netgear EX2700-100PES
   The first one is the access point for the ESP microcointroller side.
   The second one acts purely as an range extender for my internet rooter.
I have two external USB wifi antennas attached to the server.

Windows has recogniced the two wifi devices correctly.

However when I connect to one of these devices, windows does automatically disconnect from the other device and I have no clue why.

Theoretically it should be possible to run both devices at the same time, as they are in principle two sepertate network adapters...

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No version of Windows that I know of likes when you have two nics on the same subnet. You will get unexpected results at best. Are your Arduino like devices statically or dynamically configured? What end result we're you hoping for by using two wifi adapters with your server? If you absolutely need the two you will have to use either two routers (two separate WiFi networks) or a router that supports vWlans two virtual WiFi networks on the same router but technically two different lan segments. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I have two Wifi devices and one of them automatically disconnected after a brief connection. After hours of googling, I found the reason in Group policy editor. A policy located in the GPO section **Computer Configuration -> Policies ->Administrative Templates -> Network -> Windows Connection Manager** and called “**Minimize the number of simultaneous connections to the Internet or a Windows Domain**”. In the policy, select "Allow simultaneous connections" and you will immediately see the second adapter connect.